# Eclipse code fomatter not working for Java Generics code?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using eclipse code format jar file to format java code and used below maven dependecy

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.jdt.core</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.1</version>  
</dependency>
```

And when i am trying to format the below code

```
package com.editor.test;

import org.eclipse.jdt.core.ToolFactory;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.CodeFormatter;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.BadLocationException;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.Document;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.IDocument;
import org.eclipse.text.edits.MalformedTreeException;
import org.eclipse.text.edits.TextEdit;

public class FormatterTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String code = "import java.util.Map; public class TestFormatter{public static void main(String[] args){Map<String,Object> map=null;System.out.println(\"Hello World\");}}";
        CodeFormatter codeFormatter = ToolFactory.createCodeFormatter(null);
        TextEdit textEdit = codeFormatter.format(CodeFormatter.K_COMPILATION_UNIT, code, 0, code.length(), 0, null);
        IDocument doc = new Document(code);

        try {
            textEdit.apply(doc);
            System.out.println(doc.get());
        } catch (MalformedTreeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But eclipse code format not able to format code when i added generics . Can anyone tell what will be solution of this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not specifying any source level or compliance level options to `ToolFactory.createCodeFormatter` so you are probably getting a formatter that only supports the original Java without generics.

The JavaDoc for `ToolFactory.createCodeFormatter` says:

> The given options should at least provide the source level
>   (JavaCore.COMPILER_SOURCE), the compiler compliance level
>   (JavaCore.COMPILER_COMPLIANCE) and the target platform
>   (JavaCore.COMPILER_CODEGEN_TARGET_PLATFORM). Without these options, it
>   is not possible for the code formatter to know what kind of source it
>   needs to format.

So you need to do that.

Comment: Ok Map options =   JavaCore.getOptions(); it took map so i have to set value on Map and then pass to method?

Comment: Yes something like that