# Eclipse API to beautify Groovy Script code

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy

I tried the Eclipse code formatter  [Eclipse code for-matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26423492/eclipse-code-fomatter-not-working-for-java-generics-code)  to format Java code for my web project requirement. Now I am looking for something  similar for Groovy. Can any one tell me how do the same for Groovy as well?

Answer (score 3):

No syntax highlighting is so glum...!

Aaron D's recommendation to use the Eclipse Marketplace didn't work for me: versions out of date it seems, installation attempts failed. This is what worked for me (Neon, then Oxygen a few months later)

- go here https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki
- under "Snapshot builds" (lower down than "Releases", which only go up to Eclipse Luna at time of writing), identify and copy the link for your Eclipse version
- in Eclipse go Help --> Install new software
- Work with --> paste: http://dist.springsource.org/snapshot/GRECLIPSE/e4.6/ (from above site: correct version for Eclipse Neon) (2018-01-03 http://dist.springsource.org/snapshot/GRECLIPSE/e4.7/ : Oxygen)
- click add
- check the item "Groovy-Eclipse" --> Next --> Next --> Accept, Finish installed (took long time: progress indicated at bottom right)
- restart of Eclipse
- Window --> Prefs: there is now a "Groovy" item
- Groovy --> Compiler --> Groovy Script Folders: checked "**/*.gradle"
- Apply : "must do full build"...
- restart Eclipse again
- *.groovy and *.gradle : syntax highlighting! auto-formatting!

***update 2019-08, Eclipse version 4.12 ("2019-06")***

At this point there is no "Groovy-Eclipse" item to highlight/choose!
My experiments seem to show that in the "Install" dialog you have to check the "Main package" and the "Maven support" thing.

OTOH it seems that .gradle files then work with this editor out of the box, no config needed.

Thanks for making it a little bit more confusing and less self-explanatory, guys!

Comment: Now release 2.9.2 has Oxygen support. Also remember to check the "Groovy compilers (optional)", and it works like a charm! Shift-control-F to format.

Answer (score 2):

Get the [Groovy plugin](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Eclipse+Plugin) from the Eclipse marketplace (Help menu). It can format Groovy code but the result isn't as good as the one from the Java formatter (Groovy is a very complex language from a parser's point of view).

Comment: Thanks but i have to write Java code to format the Groovy code its my requirement where i will pass some code and it will return me well format code

Comment: Then look at the source code of the plugin: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Eclipse+Plugin#EclipsePlugin-DeveloperResources  The source for the formatter is here: https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/blob/e6ea796363d2d58daec4aff9d8d4a51e0e937169/ide/org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.refactoring/src/org/codehaus/groovy/eclipse/refactoring/formatter/DefaultGroovyFormatter.java

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/spidasoftware/format too. It's a command line version which is probably easier to understand.

Comment: "result isn't as good" ... at the time of writing the plugin for Oxygen seems pretty good to me... autoformatting and syntax highlighting both pretty good... but then I'm only a Groovy neophyte...

Comment: it is OK, but there's a bug where long lines are not split up.

https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/issues/624