# Eclipse 4.12 comment out multiple lines in .gradle file with hotkey

Tags: eclipse, hotkeys

Just installed a new version of Eclipse ("Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers", 2019-06 / 4.12.0) and I find that although the hotkeys Ctrl-Shift-C and Ctrl-/ work to toggle comments for blocks of code in .java files, as expected, this doesn't seem to work for my .gradle files for some unaccountable reason.

OS is Linux Mint 18.3.

Anyone know how one goes about tweaking this sort of functionality in Eclipse (i.e. so that this toggling also works in .gradle files)?

NB I also find that going Ctrl-Shift-L twice does NOT open up (as previously) the "preference page" (i.e. where you can edit key bindings). I hope they haven't messed up things here.

However you can still edit these bindings by going Windows --> Preferences --> General --> Keys. This shows no fewer than 20 (!) "Toggle Comment" bindings, with Ctrl+7, Shift+Ctrl+C and Ctrl+/. The "When" column includes things like "Editing Java Source" but also "Editing in Structured Text Editors", etc..

So I tried to add my own key binding with "When" at "Editing Text". No joy. Anyone at all familiar with this aspect of Eclipse functionality?

Comment: It is up to the editor for each language to implement this sort of thing. The gradle editor may not have implemented this.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks. Please see new edit to my question. I think it might/should be possible to tweak bindings in this way even if not set up automatically by the Gradle module/plugin.

Comment: If the gradle editor does not implement this functionality there is nothing you can do.

Comment: Tx again. Sorry, but how do you know this? In previous Eclipse installations I have been able to do this, and I can't think of any reason why Gradle should be any different to any other file (it's obviously a simple Groovy file).

Comment: Because the editor for each type of file has to implement this function separately. The editor has to understand the syntax of the type of file it is editing - this is done separately for each editor. There is no common functionality for this.

Answer (score 0):

greg-449 has the right answer.

Therefore what you have to do is install the correct Groovy editor.

I in fact gave the answer about how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26653521/eclipse-api-to-beautify-groovy-script-code/48083451#48083451) in early 2018.

It has changed ever so slightly now (for Eclipse "2019-06"/4.12), as described in my update there.

When you install that Eclipse-Groovy editor it automatically applies the various normal editing functionality not only to .groovy files but also (out of the box) to .gradle files: syntax highlighting, toggling of comments, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I did not think this worked and was about to uninstall it, then I tried selecting Open with > Groovy editor, Thought I would share a little more detail, thanks!
[image: Eclipse menu]