# Eclipse: create Gradle project but make Eclipse "accept" Groovy for app files

Tags: eclipse, gradle, groovy, configuration

I've got the dreaded red exclamation mark after creating a Gradle project and adding a .groovy file under src/main/groovy/myPackage/

I've been using Eclipse (currently 2020-09) for years and I think I'm on fairly firm ground when I say that this is about build path configuration errors.

I can build and run this project at the command line (i.e. outside Eclipse) using the Gradle wrapper. The opening lines of build.gradle look like this:

```
plugins {
    // Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
    id 'java-library'
    
    id 'eclipse'
    
    id 'application'
    
    id 'groovy'
    
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
}
mainClassName = 'gpackage.Gtest'
```

But there is no "Groovy" entry under Project --> Properties. Although under Window --> Preferences there *is* a Groovy entry, as I did this Groovy-Eclipse setup: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48083451/595305 (snapshot update site https://dist.springsource.org/snapshot/GRECLIPSE/e4.17).

If you start off by making a "Groovy Project" as opposed to a "Gradle Project", your Project --> Properties *do* include a "Groovy" entry. Is there any way to configure things to add this entry to a project started as a Gradle project?

Answer (score 0):

Well I found one answer... this may or may not be the way to do it:
Right-click on project in Package Explorer --> Configure --> Convert to Groovy project.

This has got rid of the exclamation mark. The Gradle views (Gradle Executions and Gradle Tasks) have disappeared... but these can be added back.

Project --> Properties now includes an entry "Groovy Compiler".

But... I now find that, for example, I'm getting the nasty "white cross in a red box" next to many of my import statements in the Groovy file, e.g. JavaFX import statements. Despite having the javafxplugin (see above) and also the following lines in the build.gradle file:

```
javafx {
    version = "13"
    modules = [ "javafx.controls", "javafx.fxml" ]
}
```

... I thought at first that this problem had arisen since I converted to a Groovy project, but it seems that the nasty red exclamation mark was in fact concealing the nasty white-crosses-in-red-boxes.

***Edit***

Setting up the JavaFX so that Eclipse error marks disappear is a bit of a rigmarole, but I find I documented this sufficiently after struggling for days about a year ago. It involves creating an Eclipse "User Library" containing the .jar files under /lib when you download and uncompress the JavaFX .zip, and then adding this library to the project's module path. More details can be supplied: add a comment.